# C++ - Comparing hash-value from 32 bit and 64 bit devices

Tags: android, c++, ios, c++11, hash

We're developing an app that runs on both Android and iOS. Some iOS devices require 64 bit apps now, while older ones are not capable of 64 bits. Also many android devices only support 32 bit.

Could the hash-values for Integers (int) that have the same value be different on 32 bit and 64 bit using the standard STL-hashing?

Are there other things to care for when comparing hashs from 32-bit and 64-bit devices?

Comment: You do something fundamentally wrong (Your algorithms should not depend on size of a value type)

Comment: Well, I'm just asking a question: Using two ints that have the same value - once on a 32-bit machine, once on a 64-bit machine: Will they always have the same hash-value?